# informatica problem

Tags: informatica

Facing Error:  **cannot start the server 'servername' **

when trying to start the workflow, iam getting the above error. I have configured server settings properly and it resolved as well..

all the informatica services are running fine. what could be the problem.

Comment: This would better be asked on serverfault.com. (Note: no need to post it manually - if 5 users agree and vote to close it for this reason, it will be automatically migrated over there.)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this as a wrong assignment of Integration service to workflow.
Make sure you assign a running/working Integration service to the workflow.
To assign a Integration service, Close all folders and select the Integration server from the navigation panel and select the workflow which you are trying to run and apply the settings.
Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

which version are you running ?? there could be multiple reasons for this error message, but most probably  -

your informatica server configuration is not correct, and therefore the attempt to start the server fails. As a result, when a workflow tried to execute, the attempt to connect to a running server instance fails.

I doubt if all the infa services are running fine.. if actually so, then I would reconfigure my client connection and see if you are actually hitting the right domain/service combination.

Answer (score 0):

I feel there can be multiple reason for this issue

1. Informatica Integration  services is not correctly assinged
2. Informatica services is not running
3. wrong connection

I believe informatica integration services related issue will be there.